# Get model of Laravel exceptions

Tags: php, exception, laravel, custom-exceptions

I'm trying to make custom exceptions messages with Laravel 4.2.
I use a function `firstorfail()` in a route to load a profile page, and I've made an error handler, following the doc ([link](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage))

```
App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{       
    return View::make('erreur404')->with('error', 'This user doesn\'t exist'); ;
});
```

But I would like to add custom messages (like "This user doesn't exist") for the different pages, and not the same every time this error occurs.

I've tried to access to `$e->model`, but it's a protected element so I can't have any information from the exception.

I can't use the default exception message because my website is in French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `getModel` method:

```
App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    $model = $e->getModel();

    $namespacedClassName = get_class($model);

    $className = last(explode('\\', $namespacedClassName));

    // Now do with it what you will...
});
```